# Suppose $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n=\{0,1,\dots ,n-1\}$ under addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is
Suppose $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n=\{0,1,\dots ,n-1\}$ under addition, and $k$ is the smallest positive integer in $H$ when the elements of $H$ are expresses in the form $r$ with $0\le r<n-1$. Show that $H=\langle k\rangle$.

I understand that the question is to ask me to relate subgroup H to k with regards to r. But I don't know how to connect this with ℤ.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: Hi @UiUc. Try to rephrase this in a way that shows you have attempted it. What have you tried, what do you think, etc... Then you will be less likely to get downvoted.

Comment: @gd1035 the question is to prove H=<k>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subgroup $K=\langle k\rangle \subset H$. Assume $H \neq K$. Then there exist $h \in H \backslash K$. By minimality of $k$ we obtain $k <h$. Apply division with rest aka one step of Euclidean algorithm and you obtain as rest a $s \in H$ (by subgroup law) with $s <k$ (more precise you find a $t \in Z_n$ with $h= t \cdot k +s$ and $s <k$), contradiction to minimality of $k$.